# SQL Server installed, but not showing in Windows services

Tags: sql-server

**Problem statement**

I have installed SQL Server, but when I try to run: `net start MSSQLSERVER` on the command line, I get this error:

> The service name is invalid. More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2185

**Note**: proof that I installed SQL Server: https://gyazo.com/a0140b3da72feee8152d84042eee24c3

**What I've tried**

Stack overflow:

- [SQL Server Service not available in service list after installation of SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180252/sql-server-service-not-available-in-service-list-after-installation-of-sql-serve)
- [How to find server name of SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088151/how-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server-management-studio)

DB Admin:

- [https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158604/unable-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server/172788#:~:text=On%20the%20server%2C%20go%20to,click%20and%20go%20to%20properties](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158604/unable-to-find-server-name-of-sql-server/172788#:%7E:text=On%20the%20server%2C%20go%20to,click%20and%20go%20to%20properties).

Other:

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b0734bb9-7da4-474c-bbe4-adf528dfd536/error-1060-the-specified-service-does-not-exist-as-an-installed-service?forum=netfxsetup
- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2492/why-is-sql-server-configuration-manager-missing-services/

Also, I tried using `sc sdshow MSSQLSERVER` in both CMD and PowerShell (run and not run as Admin) but it fails because of this:

> [SC] OpenService FAILED 1060: The specified service does not exist as an installed service

I know that I didn't rename the server to something else because I was never presented with the option to do so.

Comment: You probably have a named instance rather than a default instance. Open the “SQL Server Configuration Manager” program and see what’s listed under “Servers”. Also, what do you see in services.msc?

Comment: SQL Server Express will install a named instance by default btw. Which editing do you have installed?

Comment: @Dai I have installed the Developer version. And don't see SQL server under `services.msc` but only SQL Server Writer.

Comment: Sounds like your installation failed - or you didn’t select the database engine when you installed it. Re-run the installer.

Comment: Is it possible that you installed LocalDB instead of the real SQL Server? That doesn't runs the DB engine as a service, but as a normal user program.

Comment: Acutally it is possible you just did not select and service in the install and just installed the common components - but not the db services.

Comment: @Dai I reran the installer, and it worked! I have started the server successfully. Please post your answer to my question.

Comment: It says, question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines (?). Never mind, **it is very much valid and relevant question**. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Atul Questions like this should be asked on https://dba.stackexchange.com/, not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Reposting my comment as an answer):

It sounds like your installation failed - or you didn’t select the database engine when you installed it. Re-run the installer.

You can review the installer setup logs to see if and why it failed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15

Look at `%programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log\Summary.txt`.

Comment: I ran installation wizard again quickly, then I launched "SQL Server Configuration Manager" and I restarted MSSQLSERVER service. Then it started showing service in Services. Now I tried to connect using "127.0.0.1" in Microsoft Management Studio but it didn't connect. Then I used "localhost" and it connected. That was Microsoft! Many thanks for all your hints.